# シンタックスハイライトが動いていない?

Tags: バグ, 完了, シンタックスハイライト

[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

によると、以下でJavaScript用のシンタックスハイライトが有効になるはずですが、

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var a = 3;
    while(!(a < 0)){
        alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
        a--;
    }
```

有効になっていないように見えます:

```js
var a = 3;
while(!(a < 0)){
    alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
    a--;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

オンにしました。各タグのシンタックスを選ばないといけませんが、機能が使えます。