# golang の syntax highlighting について

Tags: サポート, シンタックスハイライト

golang 向けの syntax highlighting 機能が働いていない様に見受けられます。例えば、

[Golangでスライスの型を変更する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6451/golang%e3%81%a7%e3%82%b9%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ae%e5%9e%8b%e3%82%92%e5%a4%89%e6%9b%b4%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)

ではハイライトされていませんが、

[計算結果が合わない理由を教えて下さい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4450/%e8%a8%88%e7%ae%97%e7%b5%90%e6%9e%9c%e3%81%8c%e5%90%88%e3%82%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e7%90%86%e7%94%b1%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)

ではハイライトされています。同様の質問である [シンタックスハイライトが動いていない?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/180/%e3%82%b7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b9%e3%83%8f%e3%82%a4%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%8c%e5%8b%95%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84) を読んで、

```
<!-- language: lang-go -->
```

を挿入しても変化がありません。まさかとは思ったのですが、

```
<!-- language: lang-golang -->
```

としますと、ハイライト機能が働く様になりました。

デフォルトでは `lang-<tag name>` が適用されるらしいのですが、`google-code-prettify` に何か変更があったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[go](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)タグの言語設定が `<none>` （無し）になっていたので、`default` に設定しました。タグの言語設定は、[「情報」タブ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info)で確認できます。

[image: defaultに設定]

// [選択肢に lang-go が無い](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1531/30)ため、汎用設定である `default` にしてあります。

質問によってハイライトされたり、されていなかったりしたのは、一方は[ruby](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby)タグも付いていたが、もう一方は[go](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)タグのみだった、という違いによります。

[meta.seの記事](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/157841)を参考に色々試したところ、質問のタグの言語設定とハイライト機能の関係はこうなっているようです:

```sh
<none>           → ハイライトされない
                   # ハイライトされていなかった質問はこの状態だった

default          → default でハイライトされる（Google Code Prettifyにおまかせ）
                   # ハイライトされていなかった質問は今この状態

<none>, lang-rb  → lang-rb でハイライトされる
                   # ハイライトされていた質問はこの状態だった

default, lang-rb → lang-rb でハイライトされる
                   # ハイライトされていた質問は今この状態

lang-js, lang-rb → default でハイライトされる（Google Code Prettifyにおまかせ）
```

本文中のコメントでハイライト言語を上書き指定した場合も試してみました:

```sh
<!-- language: lang-go -->   
→ lang-go でハイライトされる

<!-- language: lang-aaaaa -->
→ default でハイライトされる（Google Code Prettifyにおまかせ）
  # Google Code Prettifyが理解できない設定名の場合。lang-golang はこれに該当

<!-- language: タグ名 --> + そのタグのハイライト設定が <none> または default
→ 質問のタグから割り出した言語でハイライトされる
  # lang-<tag name> ではなく <tag name> を指定

<!-- language: タグ名 --> + そのタグのハイライト設定が特定の言語
→ その言語でハイライトされる
```

私が試した時は、 `<!-- language: lang-go -->` は有効に機能していました。ただ、質問本文を編集してからプレビューのハイライトが更新されるまで 5 秒ほどかかっていたので、プレビューで確認されていた場合は、思ったより待つ必要があったのかもしれません。また、[Go mode](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#go)のハイライトは元々あまりカラフルではないようなので、有効になっていたけれど見分けが付かなかった、という可能性もあります。

Comment: 早速対応いただき、どうもありがとうございます。5秒待てなかった自分に反省してます(苦笑)。

Comment: +1 コードハイライトの言語自動伴別が賢いなーと思ってはいたのですが、タグ情報を利用していたんですねぇ。言われてみればという感じでした。

Answer (score 2):

2017年8月現在、[go](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)の言語設定は `lang-go` になっています。
このため標準では `<!-- language: lang-go -->` 相当のハイライトが付きますが、Go extension は現状[歴史的経緯](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/334#issuecomment-95295656)によりコメント部分にしか色が付きません (※)。

このため、現状では Code Prettify のデフォルトにした方がそれっぽい色が付きます。
ただし、`<!-- language: default -->` だとタグの言語設定が優先され、`lang-go` が選択されてしまいます。ワークアラウンドとして `lang-golang` をつけると一応 `default` 扱いになるようです。

なお、本家 Stack Overflow での[言語設定](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info)は `lang-golang` になっています (このような設定は存在しないので、`default` 扱いになっているのだと思います)。

(※) 実装である lang-go.js の[コメント](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-go.js#L25)にも同様のことが書いてあります。ただし、[状況が変わってきている](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/334#issuecomment-228688795)ので、その内カラフルになるかもしれません。