# monacaタグのシンタックスハイライト設定

Tags: サポート, 完了, シンタックスハイライト

現在 [monaca](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monaca) タグはデフォルトだとシンタックスハイライトが機能していないように見えます。

例: [広告（nend）を埋め込むと、背景画像が全画面表示できなくなってしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/6845/8000)

個別に `<!-- language: *** -->` を書いたりもしていたのですが、 ほとんどがHTMLないしJavascriptなので、言語設定を `lang-html` もしくは `default` にしていただけないでしょうか？

参考: [golang の syntax highlighting について](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1674/8000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defaultに設定しました。

まだ適切ではなかったら、コメントでご教示ください。